# anyone able to translate this jquery code to Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('.flip-button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.flip-card-inners').toggleClass('flip-card-active')
    })
  })
```

I wasn't able to translate this in vanilla js because I encountered several problems with get element by class

Comment: What code did you write, can you share that with us? That way you’ll learn something about your assumptions of your code that you can apply to future projects. It also demonstrates a clear attempt has been made.

Comment: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` make translating jqueery easier

Comment: The original jQuery code can already be simplified into `$('.flip-button').click(function() { $(this).closest('.flip-card-inners').toggleClass('flip-card-active') })`. The `each()` loop was superfluous here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".flip_button").forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = () => {
        element.closest('.flip-card-inners').classList.toggle("flip-card-active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.flip-button')
  .forEach((element)=> {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Do your action
    }, false);
  })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.